# Label name in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Is it possible to get a labelname in circuitikz to be equal to the output from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,every info/.style={font=\footnotesize},set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
    \draw (0,0) to[resistor={info={$R_\text{L}=\SI{220}{\ohm}$}}] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As far I've understood there's no "info" property in circuitikz, so I can't figure out how to do the same with that package. E.g., using something like

```
\draw (0,0) to[R=$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$] (2,0)
```

results in an error in circuitikz.

If possible, I'd prefer to use circuitikz over the circuits.ee.IEC library as I like the symbols in circuitikz more.

Best regards,
dm

Edit:

circuitikz example that's not working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,americanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american currents]
    \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't use `\SI`? I've had issues with `siunitx` and `pgfplots`, so it could be that it clashes with TikZ.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I get the following error: "! Extra }, or forgotten $.\@let@token ...rc@temp ) {\pgf@circ@finallabel {}}"

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me (looks nice too). I'm on an up to date TeXLive 2011 though. What are you using?

Comment: You compile fine when you use circuitikz and a command like i.e. \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$] (2,0) ?

I use TexLive 2011, which I updated about two weeks ago. But I'll run an update now and see if it works after the update.

Edit: tried to compile now after updating, still the same error when using circuitikz.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've misread the question! If possible, could you provide a nearly complete example with `circuitikz` that you'd like modified?

Comment: I added a code that's not compiling in the first post (question) now. So basically I'd like to get the same output with the circuitikz-code as I do with the other code using the circuit library in TikZ.

Until now I've usually placed symbols without labels and added the labels as nodes afterwards, but in the long run this gets time consuming and annoying. :s

Comment: Try `\draw (0,0) to[R,label=\mbox{$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$}] (2,0);`

Comment: Ah, that's what I was looking for! Thanks! Now, how do I accept a comment as an answer? Or can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I changed it to `\mbox`. Can do!

Comment: Related: [Equal (=) sign within TikZ label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110485) and [How can I put "=" in a TikZ node label specified as an option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61471) as well as [How to put a label on a wire using CircuiTikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/143001)

Comment: Notice that this problem has been fixed in `circuitikz` v1.3.0 --- you can now just use braces, as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting the label in a `\mbox` seems to do the trick. Try the following version:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,americanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american currents]
    \draw (0,0) to[R,label=\mbox{$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$}] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that TikZ thinks a `=` identifies a new option. Like in

```
(0,0) node[R,l=test=yes]
```

it is assumed that `l=tes` and `t=yes` (or something like this... At least it breaks!)

Inside a math environment, you can escape the "equals" by `{=}`:

```
(0,0) to[R,l=$R_g{=}\SI{10}{\ohm}$] ++(2,0);
```

Comment: Actually, `=yes` is just discarded. With your solution, the `=` has [wrong spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110695/16595). It would be better to do `to[R,label=${R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}}$]`. (At the most outer place, it would need eight braces because of how PGFkeys strips one pair away on the way to the actual key that deals with the labeling. I blame `circuitikz` for not inserting `{ }` again.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You’re right, and this has since been fixed, see my new answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with `circuitikz` 1.3, this issue has been fixed in the sense that you can now protect the content with outer braces just like standard TikZ:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,americanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american currents]
    \draw (0,0) to[R={$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$}] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This was fixed by @Rmano in [PR#484](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/484).