# How can I put "=" in a TikZ node label specified as an option

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

When I try to put an `=` symbol into a TikZ node label specified as an option (using `label=`), I get an error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $.
```

Is there a way to specify `=` in such cases that I'm missing?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(x){$X$};
  \path(x)[late options={label=right:=$A$}];     % Works but doesn't display anything
  \path(x)[late options={label=above:$\neq B$}]; % Works 
  \path(x)[late options={label=below:$C$}];      % Works 
  \path(x)[late options={label=left:$=D$}];      % Fails! 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Equal (=) sign within TikZ label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110485)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Key-value systems look for `=`, and can't 'tell' that the `=` here is part of the 'value'. You therefore need braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(x){$X$};
  \path(x)[late options={label={right:=$A$}}];
  \path(x)[late options={label=above:$\neq B$}]; 
  \path(x)[late options={label=below:$C$}]; 
  \path(x)[late options={label={left:$=D$}}]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(You get an error as the `=` inside math mode leaves to grouping issues, which don't happen in the first case.)

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried that too, but must have put the braces around the wrong thing.

Comment: An answer is in the pgfmanual : `/tikz/late options=⟨options⟩` with an example :  `\path (a) [late options={label=above:world}];`