# Equal (=) sign within TikZ label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I was trying to use an equal sign within a TikZ picture as a subcaption of an inner TikZ picture for comparing two images.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (p1) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (p2) at (-3,0);

        \node[label=below:$\mathcal{L}(B)$] (left) 
        {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,scale=0.56]
                \draw (p1) -- (p2);
            \end{tikzpicture}   
        };
        \node[label=below:$\mathcal{L}^*(B)\text{$=$}\mathcal{L}(D)$,right=of left]
        {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,scale=0.56]
                \draw (p2) -- (p1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My workaround was to use `\text{$=$}`. A plain equal sign instead of this will produce and error. I think TikZ recognizes this equal sign a separator of a key-value-pair of an attribute. Is there a right way to produce a plain equal-sign without this workaround?

Comment: @Toscho One should define `\equal`, but it's simply `\newcommand{\equal}{=}`

Comment: @egreg: Ah you're right. I always use a template which loads `unicode-math` which defines `\equal`.

Comment: Related: [How can I put "=" in a TikZ node label specified as an option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61471)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As already pointed out by [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110485/equal-sign-within-tikz-label?noredirect=1#comment242722_110485), the `=` is detected by TikZ that parses the options based on `,` and `=`.

This works:

```
\node[label=below:{$\mathcal{L}^*(B)=\mathcal{L}(D)$}]
```

As well as that:

```
\node[label={below:$\mathcal{L}^*(B)=\mathcal{L}(D)$}]
```

If you want to include a `:` in the label but do not specify a direction (here: `below`), then you will need to protect the colon, too:

```
\tikzset{label position=below}
\node[label=here's{:} a colon]
```

The same bracing is needed if you use `,` (in a `label` and elsewhere), for example:

```
\tikzset{nodes={draw, fill, font=\tiny}}
```

Defining a macro `\equal` as

```
\newcommand*{\equal}{=}
```

hides the `=` from the parser, too, but may not be the favorite way to input formulas.

```
\node[label=below:$\mathcal{L}^*(B)\equal\mathcal{L}(D)$]
```

At least the spacing is correct as opposed to that work-around of `\text{$=$}` where the braces `{ }` from `\text` hides `=` from the parser as well. Note that `$L{=}L$` still produces wrong spacing and isn’t an option here.

Answer (score -1):

this works nicely in my case

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
     for tree={l+=1cm} % increase level distance
        [ $X_n  \mapsto {\lim_{n=\infty} X_n=X^*} $
        [left[lleft $a+b$ ][lright]]
        [right[rleft][rright]]
      ]
 \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The trick is to apply {} barackets.

Comment: The question already has this answer. -I do not see that your code is relevant for the problem other than `{` and `}`.