# How do I change how pgfplot steps the labels along a given axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [
    minor x tick num=1,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y\mathmbox{{}={}}\frac{1}{3}x-2$
  ]
\addplot
  [
    smooth,
    blue,mark=none,
    domain=-5:10,
    samples=40
  ]
{1/3*x-2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have no idea how to get `pgfplots` to step the labels along the x-axis by 1 unit (instead of 2 as shown) without doing something funky like changing the size or compact or font used.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Though I'm not entirely happy with this.  Here's a bit of a work around which gives me the level of control I want:

```
\def\xmin{-6}
\def\xmax{10}
\def\xinc{3}
\def\xlabels{\xmin}
\multido{\nx=\xmin+\xinc}{\number\numexpr(\xmax-\xmin)/\xinc+1\relax}{
  \ifnum\nx=\xmin\else
    \xdef\xlabels{\xlabels,\nx}
  \fi
}

\def\ymin{-6}
\def\ymax{4}
\def\yinc{2}
\def\ylabels{\ymin}
\multido{\ny=\ymin+\yinc}{\number\numexpr(\ymax-\ymin)/\yinc+1\relax}{
  \ifnum\ny=\ymin\else
    \xdef\ylabels{\ylabels,\ny}
  \fi
}
```

A short-coming of this is that it will only work with interger values.

So, put into action this looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multido}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}

\def\xmin{-6}
\def\xmax{10}
\def\xinc{3}
\def\xlabels{\xmin}
\multido{\nx=\xmin+\xinc}{\number\numexpr(\xmax-\xmin)/\xinc+1\relax}{
  \ifnum\nx=\xmin\else
    \xdef\xlabels{\xlabels,\nx}
  \fi
}

\def\ymin{-6}
\def\ymax{4}
\def\yinc{2}
\def\ylabels{\ymin}
\multido{\ny=\ymin+\yinc}{\number\numexpr(\ymax-\ymin)/\yinc+1\relax}{
  \ifnum\ny=\ymin\else
    \xdef\ylabels{\ylabels,\ny}
  \fi
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}
  [
    unit vector ratio=1 1,
    minor x tick num=1,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
    xtick={\xlabels},
    ytick={\ylabels},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y\mathmbox{{}={}}\frac{1}{3}x-2$
  ]
\addplot
  [
    smooth,
    blue,mark=none,
    domain=\xmin:\xmax,
    samples=40
  ]
{1/3*x-2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it seems, given all the power `pgfplots` has to manipulate so many other aspects of the graph, that there should be a simpler approach that what I've come up with.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest but not automatically approach would be to use

```
xtick = {-5, ..., 10}
```

which will use `\foreach`’s rules for completing `...`.

If you give `xmin` and `xmax` values you can also use them

```
xmin=-5, xmax=10,
xtick={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}
```

The `pgfplots` package also provides the options `max space between ticks` and `try min ticks`, the [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), 4.14.4 “Tick Fine-Tuning”:

> `/pgfplots/max space between ticks={<number>}` (initially `35`)
>   Configures the maximum space between adjacent ticks in full points. The sux “`pt`” has to be omitted and fractional numbers are not supported.
>
> `/pgfplots/try min ticks={<number>}` (initially `4`)
>   Configures a loose lower bound on the number of ticks. It should be considered as a suggestion, not a tight limit. This number will increase the number of ticks if ‘`max space between ticks` ’ produces too few of them. The total number of ticks may still vary because not all fractional numbers in the axis’ range are valid tick positions.

Setting `max space between ticks` to `17.5` increments the *x* ticks by 1 and the *y* ticks by 0.5. The same can be said for `try min ticks = 12` but the *y* ticks will aready be doubled with a value of `8`.

(I also got rid of `\mathmbox` and replaced it by a standard `=`, the `=` just needs to be protected from `pgfkeys`’ parser, see [Equal (=) sign within TikZ label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110485/16595).)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand*{\myPlot}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[
    minor x tick num=1, axis y line=center, axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel={$y = \frac{1}{3}x-2$}, #1]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,domain=-5:10,samples=2]{1/3*x-2};
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\myPlot
\myPlot[xtick={-5,...,10}]
\myPlot[xmin=-5, xmax=10,
        xtick={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}]
\myPlot[max space between ticks=17.5]
\myPlot[try min ticks=8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty sound I would say :)