# Why labeling these nodes with an equation doesn't work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (x11) {$X_1^1$};
\node[state, right of=x11] (x12) {$X^2_1$};
\node[state, right of=x12] (x13) {$X^3_1$};
\node[state, right of=x13] (x14) {$X^4_1$};
\node[state, right of=x14] (x15) {$X^5_1$};

\node[state, below of=x11,label=left:$s\leq 3$] (x21) {$X^1_2$};
\node[state, below of=x12] (x22) {$X^2_2$};
\node[state, below of=x13] (x23) {$X^3_2$};
\node[state, below of=x14] (x24) {$X^4_2$};
\node[state, below of=x15] (x25) {$X^5_2$};

\node[state, below of=x21] (x31) {$X^1_3$};
\node[state, below of=x22] (x32) {$X^2_3$};
\node[state, below of=x23] (x33) {$X^3_3$};
\node[state, below of=x24] (x34) {$X^4_3$};
\node[state, below of=x25] (x35) {$X^5_3$};

\draw

(x11) edge[above] node{} (x21)
(x11) edge[above] node{} (x22)
(x13) edge[above] node{} (x24)
(x13) edge[above] node{} (x25)
(x15) edge[above] node{} (x23)
(x22) edge[above] node{} (x33)
(x22) edge[above] node{} (x31)
(x23) edge[above] node{} (x32)
(x25) edge[above] node{} (x34)
(x25) edge[above] node{} (x35)
;


\end{tikzpicture}
```

How come if I change `label=left:$s\leq 3$` to `label=left:$s=3$` I can no longer compile the code...

I get `! Extra }, or forgotten $`.

Comment: The answer is here: 
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110485/equal-sign-within-tikz-label

Comment: Try `label={left:$s=3$}`

Comment: Please, make your code compileable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution of your problem is given @ferahfeza comment. Note, sign `=` is used for positioning of node labels. If you have two, parser is lost. Therefore `=` in equation had to be "hidden" , i.e. had to be enclosed in curly braces.  Good practice is enclosed complete equation into curly braces, since with this spacings in equation are retained.

So, I suggest some off-topic improvements using `tikz` libraries `chains`, `positioning` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
        start chain = going right,
state/.append style = {inner sep=0pt, on chain}
                    ]
\node[state] (x11) {$X_1^1$};
\node[state] (x12) {$X^2_1$};
\node[state] (x13) {$X^3_1$};
\node[state] (x14) {$X^4_1$};
\node[state] (x15) {$X^5_1$};
%
\node[state, below= of x11,
      label=left:{$s=3$}]    % <---
             (x21) {$X^1_2$};
\node[state] (x22) {$X^2_2$};
\node[state] (x23) {$X^3_2$};
\node[state] (x24) {$X^4_2$};
\node[state] (x25) {$X^5_2$};
%
\node[state, below= of x21] (x31) {$X^1_3$};
\node[state] (x32) {$X^2_3$};
\node[state] (x33) {$X^3_3$};
\node[state] (x34) {$X^4_3$};
\node[state] (x35) {$X^5_3$};

\draw   (x11) edge ["?"]    (x21)
        (x11) edge          (x22)
        (x13) edge          (x24)
        (x13) edge          (x25)
        (x15) edge          (x23)
        (x22) edge          (x33)
        (x22) edge          (x31)
        (x23) edge          (x32)
        (x25) edge          (x34)
        (x25) edge          (x35)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good improvements (+1).

Comment: @ferahfeza, thank you very much!